# Rails create template dynamic modal

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, modal-dialog

I have a page which contains a list of buttons with exercises (exercise 1, exercise 2 etc.)

When you click one button - a modal pops up informing you with the details of the exercise + a submit button.

My question is: can I create a template modal with dynamic URL's for each exercise? I don't want to create the same modal for each exercise.

## Modal example:

```
<%= form_for @db, url: start_db_path, validate: true, :html => { :id => "startDb" } do |f| %>
<div class="modal fade" id="StartDBModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StartDBModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header text-center">
                       <h4 class="modal-title modalText title_bold">Start your Oracle Database</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                       <div class="md-form mb-5" style="text-align: center;">
                           <i class="fa fa-database icon-sizeB"><label class="modalText">Your database is:</label></i>
                           <% if $personal_db.nil? %>
                              <%= f.text_field :linuxuser, autofocus: true, :class => "form-controlS", value: "DB does not exist yet", readonly: true, :id => "nodbId" %>
                           <% else %>
                              <%= f.text_field :linuxuser, autofocus: true, :class => "form-controlS", value: $personal_db.dbname, readonly: true, :id => "startId" %>
                           <% end %> 
                       </div>
                    </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                             <%= f.button "Start Database", :class => "btn btn-warning", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Starting the database..."} %>
                          </div>
                      </div>

           </div>
        </div><!-- /.vertical-align-center -->
      </div><!-- /.alignment-helper -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- /.Start Oracle Database Modal -->
<% end %>
```

I want that URL to be dynamic and the same modal for every exercise button but with different URL's

Thanks,
Razvan

Comment: Yes, you can. Most lightbox/modal implementations I've seen, including bootstrap (which you seem to be using here) support dynamic content inclusion. Consult the docs.

Comment: HI, what I am trying to do can be done somehow with javascript. But I wonder if there is another way (a simpler one)